# macOS accessibility API on WebKit applications with AXTextMarker

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, macos-carbon

I need to access data from webkit applications such as Safari, Mail and maybe others. I can see in the `Accessibility Inspector` there is :`AXTextMarker` and `AXTextMarkerForRange`.

I tried the usual way to get this info :

```
AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();    //creating system wide element
AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;

AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);                //Copy the focused
if (error != kAXErrorSuccess){
    NSLog(@"Could not get focused element");
}else{
    AXValueRef marker = NULL;
    AXError getTextValueError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXMarkerUIElementsAttribute , (CFTypeRef *)&marker);        
}
```

`kAXMarkerUIElementsAttribute` is the only thing I can see with Marker but everything is empty each time.

I guess for security reasons, I cannot access them? Is there any way possible. I am developing an app for people with difficulties reading and it could really help.

Thanks

Comment: `kAXMarkerUIElementsAttribute` is a ruler-specific attribute. `AXTextMarkerRef` and `AXTextMarkerRangeRef` are types. The attributes are `"AXStartTextMarker"`, `"AXEndTextMarker"` and `"AXSelectedTextMarkerRange"`.

Comment: Yes thank you but i dont have this value : Use of undeclared identifier 'kAXStartTextMarker'.

Comment: Use string `@"AXStartTextMarker"`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i get a TextMarker object, i can't find any doc on this, what is exactly the start and end markers. I guess i can convert them to string? Also, the AXSelectedTextMarkerRange seems to return always the same range.

Comment: I think "AXSelectedTextMarkerRange" returns a `AXTextMarkerRangeRef`.

Comment: What is your goal, which data do you want to get? It is possible to get some info about the text markers from the UI Element.

Comment: I want to get the selected text in safari, which i can do now thanks but i also need the bounds of the selected range.

Comment: @hugo411, did you find the way to get bounds of selected text?

Comment: @KrishnaMaru Humm, i only needed the selected text for my application. Check if there is a kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute for the text marker using the accesibility tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tips and tricks:

Ask `focussedElement` for its supported attributes. Use the functions:

```
AXError AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(AXUIElementRef element, CFArrayRef  _Nullable *names);
```

> Returns a list of all the attributes supported by the specified accessibility object.

and

```
AXError AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeNames(AXUIElementRef element, CFArrayRef  _Nullable *names);
```

> Returns a list of all the parameterized attributes supported by the specified accessibility object.

Most undocumented attributes are self explanatory.

For example get the selected text as attributed string:

```
CFTypeRef markerRange = NULL;
AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement, (CFStringRef)@"AXSelectedTextMarkerRange", &markerRange);
CFTypeRef result = NULL;
error = AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(focussedElement, (CFStringRef)@"AXAttributedStringForTextMarkerRange", markerRange, &result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. i guess my problem came from CFTypeRef, i was using AXUIElementRef.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I haven't tested this but I found some research on the API and I think this may solve your problem.

It seems for the accessibility API to fully work the application needs to be trusted or basically have root access. Is the application running in root?

I found some apple script from a past project. seemed relevant

```
NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary new];
NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@ %@\" with administrator privileges", @"/usr/sbin/lsof",@"-c filecoord"];
NSLog(@"Running... %@",script);
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

This apple script isn't excatily what you need but its a start. I'm not sure how to fully request root access to an application from inside the application its self, 
But for testing, you can always just run your application as root and continue your debugging

Please let me know if this helped you in any way or not

Comment: Hey, i should have specify that i am building a .dylib lib from my Xcode project. This dylib is loaded by a java application. Everything works fine but i just can't have access to stuff inside webkit applications. Thanks ill investigate if root access can be the cause.