# find Selected text's Range from Safari and Mail

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari, applescript, accessibility

I want to find out selected text's Range for Safari and Mail application. 
I have tried Accessibility to find it out, I am able to find the text range for all other application other than these 2.

```
AXValueRef selectedRangeValue = NULL;
    AXError getSelectedRangeError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement,   kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&selectedRangeValue);
```

I have tried AppleScript also, but it works fine for me only for MSWord.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
                activate
                return selection start of selection
            end tell
```

Please let me know if there is any way to find out the Selected Text's Range for Safari and Mail. Anything extension/ScriptBridging/AppleScript/Accessibility, which gives result for this.

Comment: What values are you looking for exactly in the range? An example would be helpful.

Comment: @l'L'l , I want NSRange, which contains Starting position of String and Length of the String. as I told, I have already tried Accessibility (which gives Location and length) & AppleScript (Which gives start and end location).

Comment: Once again there is no common way for all applications. How about an Automator Service which is able to get and process selected text.

Comment: @vadian , do you mean Automator app? if yes, then , that is also using AppleScript for any action. and I want these value in my Mac osx app. let me know if I am getting anything wrong, I don't have much knowledge about automator service.

Comment: I didn't get that you want to implement the functionality in a Cocoa app. I'm not sure that you can run Automator Services from [NSUserAutomatorTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserautomatortask)

Comment: Can you see the selected text range in Accessibility Inspector?

Comment: @Willeke, No I am not able to get selected text range in Accessibility Inspector for Mail. There is "AXTextMarkerRange".

Comment: See [macOS accessibility API on WebKit applications with AXTextMarker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021777/4244136)

Comment: @Willeke, I have gone through this link, and got value for "AXSelectedTextMarkerRange", but I am not getting how can I use those value. Using those values I have to highlight the word at specific range.

Comment: You can get the length of the range with `AXBoundsForTextMarkerRange`, I don't know how to get the location. How do you highlight a word?