# How to get highlighted text from apps like Mail.app in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

Below is a snippet that prints highlighted text, however, it does not work with all apps. For instance, one app I know it does not work with is Mail.

What attributes should I be searching for to get the highlighted text in apps like Mail :)

```
func getHighlightedText() -> AnyObject? {
    let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
    var focusedElement: AnyObject?
    let focusedCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, "AXFocusedUIElement" as CFString, &focusedElement)
    if (focusedCode == AXError.success) {
        var selectedText: AnyObject?
        let textCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement as! AXUIElement, "AXSelectedText" as CFString, &selectedText)
        if (textCode == AXError.success) {
            return selectedText
        }
    }
    return nil
}
sleep(3) #enough time to switch to another app and highlight the text
print(getHighlightedText())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macOS accessibility API on WebKit applications with AXTextMarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877190/macos-accessibility-api-on-webkit-applications-with-axtextmarker)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the one! Thank you!