# Select Text in Webkit applications via macOS accessibility API

Tags: swift, macos, webkit, accessibility

I need to select text in a WebKit view of another application (Apple Mail) using accessibility APIs.

For regular text fields, I do something like this:

```
func selectText(withRange range: CFRange) throws {
    var range = range
    guard let newValue: AXValue = AXValueCreate(AXValueType.cfRange, &range) else { return }
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(self, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, newValue)
}
```

However, in the composing window of Apple Mail every text seems to be of type `Static Text` which doesn't come with the necessary `AXSelectedTextRange`

It has `AXSelectedTextMarkerRange`, though, which requires an `AXTextMarker`. I just don't get how to create one of these. I have no trouble reading the text from a user created selection using this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877190/macos-accessibility-api-on-webkit-applications-with-axtextmarker), but I'm unable to select text via the accessibility APIs.

Comment: Is `AXTextMarkerForIndex` among the names returned by `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeNames`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke) I was able to figure it out. It is indeed possible to do it using `AXTextMarkerForIndex`. Knowing that it's actually pretty straightforward.

Here's my code:

```
func getTextMarker(forIndex index: CFIndex) throws -> AXTextMarker? {
        var textMarker: AnyObject?
        guard AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(self,"AXTextMarkerForIndex" as CFString, index as AnyObject, &textMarker) == .success else { return nil }
        return textMarker as! AXTextMarker
}

func selectStaticText(withRange range: CFRange) throws {
        guard let textMarkerStart = try? getTextMarker(forIndex: range.location) else { return }
        guard let textMarkerEnd = try? getTextMarker(forIndex: range.location + range.length) else { return }
        let textMarkerRange = AXTextMarkerRangeCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, textMarkerStart, textMarkerEnd)

        AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(self, "AXSelectedTextMarkerRange" as CFString, textMarkerRange)
}
```

Comment: I tried this with a Mail editor window. The element role is `AXWebArea` but return from `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeNames` does not contain `AXTextMarkerForIndex`.

Comment: I tried `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeNames` too, with no luck.

Comment: @soundflix does this `AXWebArea` have child elements?

Comment: @Willeke, my `AXWebArea` has 3 children `AXGroup` without title, one of them has children `AXStaticText` with a count equal to my email body's lines. In those `AXStaticText` I can find the lines of text in `AXValue`. But how to get and set the `AXTextMarker`?

Comment: @soundflix I think it's better to ask a new question where you can post your code.